Webcam mic not working on Teams
Hello to all the expertise out there.
I am baffled by this issue with Teams.  The mic from my webcam just refuses to work.
Here are some details:

Mic works perfectly with google meet and zoom.
Mic doesn't work with the browser web version of teams or the app (teams-for-linux).  I basically just select my webcam mic and I get nothing.
I have tried mutiple mics from webcams including two logitec mics and a generic mic from amazon (nexigo).  All get the same result of no input from the mic.
I have tried the solution here: Webcam microphone not working [NEXIGO] Basically, alsamixer shows that the webcam volume is at 0.  When I try to bring it to 100, it forces it back to 0.
There is no usb hub or anything between the pc and the mic.
Using pulseaudio volume control, I see the webcam mic registering the input and registering audio coming in, but still no input in Teams.

I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 and this also happened on Ubuntu 22.  I have tried other distros including Debian and Pop Os with the same results.
Any thoughts?
Has anyone had any success with this?

try "alsamixer" command unmute

Thanks.  How do I input the "unmute" command in alsamixer?
